# Angular 7, create new object with some values from object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have object like this

```
const Obj =
"Value1": {
    "value1value": "1"
},
"Value2": {
    "value2value": "2"
},
"Value3": {
    "value3value": "3"
},
"BTest": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
},
"Value4": {
    "value4value": "value4value"
},
"ATest": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
},
"Value5": {
    "value5value": "value5value",
    "value6value": "value6value"
},
"TestA": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
};
```

What i need is to create new object that will look like this

```
cont newObject = 
    "Value1": {
        "value1value": "1"
    },
    "Value2": {
        "value2value": "2"
    },
    "Value3": {
        "value3value": "3"
    },
    "Value4": {
        "value4value": "value4value"
    },
    "Value5": {
        "value5value": "value5value",
        "value6value": "value6value"
    };
```

Some values are removed, i have tried with like

```
const newObject = Obj.map(o => {
          return {  };
        });
```

But i had no luck, does somebody knows what has to be done, thanks in advance

Comment: So you want all keys which starts with **Value***?

Comment: No this is just example values, it can be any name

Comment: @MiomirDancevic  delete the property that you don't want `['BTest', 'ATest','TestA'].forEach(e => delete obj[e]);`

Comment: This is better solution :) I have asked here question, maybe you can write an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620649/remove-some-values-from-object-angular-7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) combined with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```js
const Obj = {"Value1": {"value1value": "1"},"Value2": {"value2value": "2"},"Value3": {"value3value": "3"},"BTest": {"1": "1","2": "2"},"Value4": {"value4value": "value4value"},"ATest": {"1": "1","2": "2"},"Value5": {"value5value": "value5value","value6value": "value6value"},"TestA": {"1": "1","2": "2"}};
const result = Object.assign(
  {},
  ...Object.keys(Obj)
    .filter(k => k.startsWith('Value'))
    .map(k => ({ [k]: Obj[k] }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: running your code give results as an array like `[
  {
    "Value1": {
      "value1value": "1"
    }
  }.....` but op want result as object

Comment: Ups @jitender, I have fixed code solution.. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to extract keys which starts with specific value so you can do something like

```js
var obj={"Value1": {
    "value1value": "1"
},
"Value2": {
    "value2value": "2"
},
"Value3": {
    "value3value": "3"
},
"BTest": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
},
"Value4": {
    "value4value": "value4value"
},
"ATest": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
},
"Value5": {
    "value5value": "value5value",
    "value6value": "value6value"
},
"TestA": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
}}

let newObj={};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k=>{
if(k.startsWith('Value')){
newObj[k]=obj[k];
}
})
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `startwith` etc and want to use full names how about this, You create an array with the names that you want to remove and than simply check add keys that are not in that array to new object. Something like this

```
const removeableItems = ["TestA", "BTest", "ATest"]
let newObj = {}
for (var key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !removeableItems.includes(key)) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
   }
}
```

Here is a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ul4yyf) showing this.

Comment: Op want to filter object keys not an array

Comment: It is filtering object keys and not array if you look at stack blitz link. I myself added the array for keys that needs to be removed.

Comment: {Value1: {…}, Value2: {…}, Value3: {…}, Value4: {…}…}. If you look at the console.